# When Video stream load in constraint layou it hide relativelayout view which publishing my own camera in Android?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, tokbox

I am creating app which required to communicate over live video call. For this i used
(https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/) Tokbox API (Vonage API).
Bottom right corner camera is my camera. And Full screen camera is opponent camera.

**Issue:**
When i run the app in android 8 OS version. It perfectly works fine It shows both video.
When i run the app in android 10 OS version it hide my own bottom corner video when opponent video call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mPublisherViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNoAttendees"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_participant"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtWaitAttendees" />

        <com.app.readyb.customview.textview.CustomTextAxiReg
            android:id="@+id/txtWaitAttendees"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgNoAttendees"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relPublisherView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_130sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp" />

    <include layout="@layout/cm_bottom_sheet_persistent" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Android OS 8 Screenshot**

[image: Android OS 8]

**Android OS 10 Screenshot**

[image: Android OS 10]
[image: Android OS 10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't like to give an answer to my own question but I want to do it because it will help other developers.

This line I need to add in after session connected.

```
if (mPublisher.getView() instanceof GLSurfaceView) {
            ((GLSurfaceView) mPublisher.getView()).setZOrderOnTop(true);
        }
```